# Firestore - performance issue when retrieving document fields

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I have a web application where users can view images, every day 20-30 thousand new images are uploaded on my site, each image must store some information (who made it, what filters, upload time, etc.) I store the id of images in the Firestore collection, the id of each document in this collection is the id of the image and inside this document are fields with the necessary information for this image.

This is my first website and first project, this is the first time I've come across this and want to ask if there are better ways to store information about an image so that I can retrieve it quickly later? (I tried to write information in metadata, it takes a long time to get it later...) I ran into a problem after the number of images on my site reached about 200k (and 200k documents in the Firestore collection), every time you go to a page with a certain image, you need about 1.5 -2 seconds to load all image information.

My general question is how to store image information when there are a lot of them and all users can view these images on the page where all the information about this image will be (There is a main image feed and each image has its own page).
How to quickly get information about each image? What is the most efficient way?

My current approach:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const imageDocRef = doc(db, 'images', imageId);

        getDoc(imageDocRef)
            .then(doc => {
                if (doc.exists()) {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const info1 = data.info1;
                    const info2 = data.info2;
                    const info3 = data.info3;
                    ......
```

With over 200k documents this one takes about 2 seconds to retrieve all information needed.

Create collection, wait until they fill up to 200-300 thousand documents and then create a new collection? Sounds dumb, right?

On other component I have an image feed, I use query and pagination (infinite image feed) -

```
        let queryRef = collection(db, "images");
        queryRef = query(queryRef, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), limit(20));

        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryRef);
                    const imageIds = querySnapshot.docs
                        .map((doc) => {
                            const imageId = doc.id; // This is how i get id of image (doc name = image id)
```

This works perfectly, and my image feed is loading really fast.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to store image information when there are a lot of them"? Whats is wrong in the way you're currently storing the images?